# Can If else statement be executed in adapterclass?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does if else statement get executed in adapter class?

I'm trying to make a notification message like Shopee apps. So I want user to receive notification if the admin have submitted the customer tracking number, the customer will received message in the notification page that will displayed the text including their tracking number. If they don't have the tracking number yet. The notification will not supposed to be displayed on the customer page.

the yellow highlighted is the correct output but the red line is not. That notification was not supposed to come out yet because the admin has not been updated the customer order tracking number.

[my apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2pba.jpg)

[this is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkfMX.png)

`adapter class`

```
     public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
            if (orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum() == ""){
                myViewHolder.note.setText("Your order has not been shipped yet!" +orderList.get(i).dateTime);


            }
            else

            myViewHolder.note.setText(" Your order ID :" + orderList.get(i).getDateTime()+" has been posted. The Tracking number is :" + orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum());
    }
```

`notificationClass`

```
    protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if (dbNotification != null) {
                dbNotification.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            orderList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (DataSnapshot orderSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : orderSnapShot.getChildren()) {
                                    orderList.add(ds.getValue(Order.class));


                                }
                            }

                        }

                        notificationAdapter NotificationAdapter = new notificationAdapter(orderList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(NotificationAdapter);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(CustNotification.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```
public class Order {
    public String cust_id;
    public String cart_id;
    public String total;
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String phone;
    public String status;
    public String dateTime;
    public String courier;
    public String trackingNum;
    public String methodPay;


    public Order() {
    }

    public Order(String cust_id, String cart_id, String total, String name, String address, String phone, String status, String dateTime,String courier, String trackingNum, String methodPay) {
        this.cust_id = cust_id;
        this.total = total;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.cart_id = cart_id;
        this.status = status;
        this.dateTime=dateTime;
        this.courier=courier;
        this.trackingNum=trackingNum;
        this.methodPay=methodPay;
    }
```

Comment: You can't use `==` when comparing a `String`, you will get unintended results. Change `orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum() == ""` to `orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum().equals("")`. You could even use `orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum().isEmpty()` to check if the tracking number is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question explicitly -- Yes, you can use logic such as if-else inside your `onBindViewHolder()` method.

As for why your logic may not be working, maybe you should change your if statement to use [TextUtils.isEmpty](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) and see if that works.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum())) {
        myViewHolder.note.setText("Your order has not been shipped yet!" + orderList.get(i).dateTime);

    } else {
        myViewHolder.note.setText(" Your order ID :" + orderList.get(i).getDateTime() + " has been posted. The Tracking number is :" + orderList.get(i).getTrackingNum());
    }
}
```